# Jenkins plugin populate drop down dynamically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any existing jenkins plugin which dynamically populates drop down menu based on values retrieved from a rest api call?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using [Extended Choice Parameter](http://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter) to implement something.